# Exporting Classify Models

Tags: external-calls, webservices, machine-learning

Currently I have created a simple classifier to classify sentiment from a string of text (or a tweet). The code is very basic and looks something like this:

```
data1 = SemanticImport[file];
c = Classify[data1[[2 ;;, 2]] -> data1[[2 ;;, 1]]]
result = c[testData[[2]]]
{'Happy'}
```

But I'd like to use it in my own application which has been written in C#. Is there a way to take this classifier and use it outside of the notebook either by (1) exporting code that created the classifier or (2) creating a Cloud API to send a JSON file to receive the intended request.

Comment: It's possible to export an `LogisticRegression` Model of Classify.

Comment: Is there any updates on this? Is it possible to export `ClassifierFunction` in general?